# How do I obtain Kotlin/JS dependency files

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js

As of Kotlin 1.3.41, the kotlin js compiler would produce the js files for dependencies (e.g. the standard lib kotlin.js). In Kotlin 1.3.50 and 1.3.60, these dependencies are no longer produced.

How is one supposed to obtain these files separately or get the kotlin compiler to produce them again?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to go away if we switch to "compile" instead of "implementation" for the dependencies in the build.gradle file.